# A tyoi rebus chalenge

Tags: rebus

See if you can solvr this rebus:

> tyoi

Hint wich will help in most cases:

> Look down

Comment: Please do not edit this puzzle.

Comment: Ack - 3 of u have got it. I put too many clues in this.

Comment: *edits the puzzle to make it harder* hehehe

Comment: I'm tempted to for future comers, to be honest

Comment: Nah, it's okay to have a puzzle, now and again, that's not terribly difficult.  It was still a good puzzle. :)

Comment: When I first saw this I thought it was in another language. Didn't even spot the connection with solvr! I feel embarrased

Comment: I agree with Khale, its easy but +1 for coming up with it - its a clever idea

Comment: Not sure what the missing 'h' in "which" is for, other than to make the other "errors" seem less obvious...

Comment: It was me overdoing things tbh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

is it

> typo

because

> solvr -> solve is a typo, wich -> which, and the *oi* in *tyoi* are off by one key, on a standard QWERTY layout. "Look down" implies looking at the keyboard as you type, to make sure the right keys are pressed.

Comment: I believe you posted the answer first, and in addition, have explained how it works. However, I'll accept it only when the hint has been explained too (it shouldn't be too hard) :)

Comment: Edited my answer to include the hint explanation

Comment: Nice one - you have it

Answer (score 4):

Based on the typing errors in the question and title, the answer is:

> typo

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer is

> Typo